# Flask-SQLAlchemy. Using session.query to print a text in one table corresponding to its id written in another table

Tags: python, mysql, sql, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am new to SQL.

I have 2 tables 'doc' and 'code' in my MySQL Database.
One of the column in doc is code_id.

During a query to get all data from 'doc' table, I want the code_id to be replaced by the column 'text' in the table 'code' corresponding to the id number in 'code_id'

Example:
Table-doc

| id | text | code_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Water | 3 |
| 2 | Air | 1 |

Table-code

| id | text |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Skydiving |
| 2 | Badminton |
| 3 | Swimming |

An entry in 'doc' table for column 'code_id' is 3. The data in column 'text' with id as 3 in table 'code' is 'Swimming'. When I retrieve this information through code `result=db.session.query(doc)`, I want to replace the '3' with 'Swimming' and get the data in this format.

What would be the query to get this result?

Comment: Hi, I have just updated the question to add the tables. I will also try the query you have suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you need  a simple join:
You should keep in mind that text is a reserved word on MySQL and you should not name your columns with reserved words.

```
create table doc (
id int(9) not null auto_increment,
`text` varchar(30),
code_id int(9) not null,
Primary key id(`id`) );

insert into  doc values (1,'Water',3), (2,'Air',1) ; 

create table code (
id int(9) not null auto_increment,
text varchar(30),
Primary key sid(`id`)  );


insert into code values (1,'Skydiving'), (2,'Badminton'), (3,'Swimming') ;
```

And your query would be like:

```
 SELECT doc.*, code.text from doc inner join code on doc.code_id= code.id;
```

[image]

I let `code_id` in `select` query only for explanation, you can remove it from your query.